# RuntimeErrorenvironment Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant User + Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, circular-dependency

After removing active_admin i am getting this error from production. Please help me how do i solved this error.

```
app/admin/user.rb:1<top (required)>


ActiveAdmin.register User do
# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
#
# permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
```

Comment: why you need ```app/admin/user.rb``` if you removed active_admin

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the activeadmin gem, you need to delete all files from `app/admin` and one line from your routes.rb `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`

Comment: Yes, I have removed all the file but still getting this issue from production. No issue from local and staging. 

Any idea..?

Comment: RuntimeErrorenvironment
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant User

Comment: I am getting this error when my scheduler run on production. Any idea what could be the reason behind this.?

Comment: Did you have restarted the scheduler? Did you really deleted the files in `app/admin` even on the prod server?

Comment: Yes I restarted the sidekiq.