# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant User + After removing active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin, circular-dependency

I was using active admin but mistakenly integrated in wrong repo. When I found it and I removed everything about active admin from that repo but still find issue related to active admin. Don't understand how my application find that admin namespace part on server.

Error :-

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant User
app/admin/user.rb:1<top (required)>
RuntimeError·Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant User
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeErrorenvironment Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Use + Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249562/runtimeerrorenvironment-circular-dependency-detected-while-autoloading-constant)

Comment: I am still facing the problem that's why i asked again.